# I'm trying to install programs/apt upgrade and this group of libs aren't allowing me to do so

Tags: apt, software-center, dpkg, dependencies

I can't `apt-get upgrade`, I also tried installing software with the software center but no luck since those libs need dependencies. I tried removing them but that didn't work and I also tried various other commands, like `sudo apt-get clean`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, `sudo apt-get remove`,  `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, and `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Software Center:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 206010 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev-i386 (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/bits', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.6
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.6_amd64.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gcc-4.8-multilib:
 gcc-4.8-multilib depends on libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11); however:
  Package libc6-dev-i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gcc-4.8-multilib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6-dev-x32:
 libc6-dev-x32 depends on libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.6); however:
  Package libc6-dev-i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libc6-dev-x32 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gcc-multilib:
 gcc-multilib depends on gcc-4.8-multilib (>= 4.8.2-5~); however:
  Package gcc-4.8-multilib is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gcc-multilib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of g++-4.8-multilib:
 g++-4.8-multilib depends on gcc-4.8-multilib (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1); however:
  Package gcc-4.8-multilib is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package g++-4.8-multilib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of g++-multilib:
 g++-multilib depends on gcc-multilib (>= 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6); however:
  Package gcc-multilib is not configured yet.
 g++-multilib depends on g++-4.8-multilib (>= 4.8.2-5~); however:
  Package g++-4.8-multilib is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package g++-multilib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

`apt-get upgrade`:

```
keegan@keeganserver:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-4.8-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not installed
 libc6-dev-x32 : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

With `-f`:

```
keegan@keeganserver:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cpp-4.4 diffstat gcc-4.4-base intltool-debian libalgorithm-diff-perl
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libapt-pkg-perl
  libarchive-zip-perl libautodie-perl libclass-accessor-perl libclone-perl
  libdpkg-perl libemail-valid-perl libfile-fcntllock-perl libio-pty-perl
  libio-string-perl libipc-run-perl libipc-system-simple-perl
  liblist-moreutils-perl libnet-dns-perl libnet-domain-tld-perl libnet-ip-perl
  libparse-debianchangelog-perl libperlio-gzip-perl libsub-identify-perl
  libsub-name-perl libtext-levenshtein-perl libupstart1 patchutils t1utils
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev-i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev-i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,148 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,333 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 206010 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev-i386 (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/bits', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.6
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.6_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Run this sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends gcc

Comment: then try sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: Thought it was going to work until...http://pastebin.com/4CSwdgQD

Comment: have you run this dpkg --purge --force-depends gcc and then tried update /upgrade or just trying to update and upgrade ?

Comment: @Ma5ter If this is solved please accept an answer, or post the solution for others to use and then accept it. This site doesn't use `[solved]` to mark it as solved.

Comment: I dont know where this "accept" button is, looking around..idk i feel stupid..

Answer (score 1):

try this

just press Ctrl+Alt+T on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

at first, delete damaged files by `rm` command:

```
sudo rm -fr  /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.6_amd64.deb
```

now, change your `sources.list`

generate your new list from here:

http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

copy all the lines and replace them instead of yours (use your favorite editor, i used vim here)

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bk
sudo vim.tiny /etc/apt/sources.list
```

now run these lines:

```
sudo apt-get  clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```